# How to hand over a specific parameter

Tags: c#, autofac

Assume that I have the following classes with their interfaces

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    int _value;

    public MyService (int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}


public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    IMyService _myService;

    public MyClass(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}
```

Step 1:  Setting up a constructor inside my test project using autofac:

```
public class Configuration : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Step 2: Set up test

```
public class MyApplication
{
    readonly int _value = 1234;
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public MyApplication(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }
}
```

Now, how do I inject the parameter "value" which is unknown by the configurator but known by "MyApplication"?

Before the idea was to do this

```
public class MyApplication
{
    readonly int _value = 1234;
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public MyApplication()
    {
        _myService = new MyService(_value);
        _myClass = new MyClass(_myService);
    }
}
```

But now I am trying to us dependency inversion and dependency injection ending up in the above described problem.

Comment: Have you read the docs on how to [pass parameters at registration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html) or pass them [at resolution time](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html)? There are several options.

Comment: Thx for that input. No haven't seen it yet, but it looks interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the constructor in the autofac configuration.

```
builder.Register((comCont, parameters) => new MyClass(123))
  .As<IMyClass>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Thx for your input. The deal would be that I may have different "MyApplications"-Classes containing individual "_value" still using the identical configurator. May I have to assign this value outside the constructor to achieve that?

Comment: @RadioMan85 - It depends on where this information is coming from. Is it a config file (like web.config or a json) then you should create some type of class that can retrieve the config info at runtime and then you read it in your `MyClass` instance (injecting that config reader too of course).

Comment: Well not a entire config file but at least a configuration value that probably requests the same solution. I'll take that.

Comment: Thx for your inputs